# Sql - Не получается выбрать строки с разными условиями

Tags: sql, firebird

Доброе время суток,
Суть: есть таблица (*DEVICES*), в которой, есть *ID* заявки (*PROPOSAL_ID*) на работу. По каждой заявке может быть разный вид работ (*SORT_WORK_ID*), например заявка с PROPOSAL_ID=30 (а также с разными суммами оплат), для которой вид работ: *штукатурка*, *побелка*, *покраска* соответственно с ID: *1*, *2*, *3* см. рис.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне нужно каким-то образом, вытягивать *PROPOSAL_ID*, только тех заявок, для которых пользователь выделил определенный вид работ.

Например:
- Если пользователь выделил вид работ с *SORT_WORK_ID* = 1, т.е. «штукатурка», должна находится заявка только с штукотуркой, т.е. *PROPOSAL_ID* = 25.
- Если пользователь выделил вид работ с *SORT_WORK_ID* = (1,2), то должны находится только заявки с штукатуркой и побелкой, т.е. PROPOSAL_ID = 28, 29
- Если пользователь выделил вид работ с *SORT_WORK_ID* = (1,2, 3), то должны находится только заявки с штукатуркой и побелкой и покраской, т.е. PROPOSAL_ID = 30.

И как еще этот запрос ограничить *combobox*`ом строгий поиск (*галочка стоит*) или нет (*галочки нет*):
 -- т.е. если строгий, то в результате запроса в него должны входить (*PROPOSAL_ID*) только те виды работ, которые выбрал пользователь (например пользователь выбрал *SORT_WORK_ID* = 1, тогда должна выбираться заявка с *PROPOSAL_ID* = 25 или *SORT_WORK_ID* in (1, 2), то *PROPOSAL_ID* = 28, 29);
 -- если не строгий, то в результат могут входить заявки с джругими видами работ *SORT_WORK_ID* = 1, то в результат попадут все заявки, т.к. все они имеют вид работы равный «1»

Мой вариант (но он не совсем рабочий - при  *SORT_WORK_ID in (1,2,3)* - не работает и не учитывает - "*строгий*" поиск или нет):

```
select q.proposal_ID, count(*) from (select PROPOSAL_ID, SORT_WORK_ID, count(*) p from DEVICES D where
SORT_WORK_ID in (1,2)
group by PROPOSAL_ID, D.SORT_WORK_ID
having count(*) > 1) q
group by PROPOSAL_ID
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: 1) какой диалект SQL - mysql или firebird/interbase? И какая версия сервера?

Comment: 2) приведите структуру таблиц

Comment: dialect 3, firebird 3.0.3

Comment: тут вообщем -то таблица одна пока, дальше думаю будут

Comment: Я дополнил мой вопрос, соим вариантом запроса, но он не совсем правильно работает

Comment: таблица с названием *DEVICES* - но это врядли поможет

Comment: *для которых пользователь выделил определенный вид работ* Пользователь - выделяет на клиенте. SQL-сервер об этом ни сном ни духом. Сперва решите, как именно Вы намерены передать серверу эту информацию.

Answer (score 1):

Если пара PROPOSAL_ID, SORT_WORK_ID является уникальной в DEVICES:

```
select q.proposal_ID
from (
  SELECT D.PROPOSAL_ID, SUM(CASE WHEN D.SORT_WORK_ID IN (1,2) /*Тут подставить список выбранных */ THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_SELECTED, COUNT(*) AS COUNT_ALL
  FROM DEVICES D
  GROUP BY D.PROPOSAL_ID
) q
where q.COUNT_SELECTED = 2 /*тут подставить кол-во выбранных */
  and q.COUNT_SELECTED = COUNT_ALL /* для нестрогого поиска убрать эту строку */
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, будем смотреть,
Вот тут еще вариант:

```
SELECT Q.proposal_id
  FROM (
    SELECT proposal_id, sort_work_id
      FROM Devices
      GROUP BY proposal_id, sort_work_id) Q
  GROUP BY Q.proposal_id
  HAVING Count(*)=2 AND SUM(CASE WHEN Q.sort_work_id IN (1,2) 1 ELSE 0 END)=2   //строгое

  HAVING Count(*)>=2 AND SUM(CASE WHEN Q.sort_work_id IN (1,2) 1 ELSE 0 END)=2  //не строгое
```